# Alterar a cor da Seleção da Borda com o Mouse

Tags: delphi

Olá, tenho a seguinte função abaixo na qual eu seleciono (com o mouse) uma determinada coordenada de uma imagem e a salvo. Acontece que quando é uma imagem muito CLARA ou BRANCA eu não consigo ver o espaço que estou selecionando!

Existe alguma forma de mudar a cor da "borda" da Seleção que estou fazendo na imagem?

Vou salvar somente a parte que seleciono a imagem.

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsDown then
  begin
    Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
    Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNotXor;
    Canvas.Rectangle(OldStartX, OldStartY, OldEndX, OldEndY);
    OldEndX := X;
    OldEndY := Y;
    Canvas.Rectangle(StartX, StartY, X, Y);
  end;
end;
```

Segue um PRINT explicando exatamente qual BORDA eu quero mudar: http://prntscr.com/9bgj90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem como sim amigo, porem, como a linha da borda é muito fina, é provável que você precisara fazer alguns ajustes.

Adicione essa propriedade abaixo da `pmNotXor`:

```
Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed; //ou a cor de sua escolha
```

Se precisar deixar a borda mais expessa você pode usar:

```
Canvas.Pen.Width := 2; //ou qualquer tamanho de sua escolha
```

Mas para a propriedade `Width` ficar legal, você terá que escolher alguns estilos de linha para ficar legal.

Aguardo o Feedback!

Comment: Perfeito @Júnior Moreira, muito obrigado!